# Items in linear layout don't fit properly on screen

Tags: java, android

I am using a linear layout to display image views wrappedh inside a relative layout. I want the image views to appear occupy to the whole width of the screen horizontally with no spaces in between for all screen types.
However, i still get unwanted spaces between the views. I need help on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_main"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/img_audio"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/img_event"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/img_video" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/img_more"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to place images in horizontal order of the screen?

Comment: yeah. but it doesnt fill the width

Comment: It shouldn't be because it corresponds to the size of your images and the screen width. Maybe you can get the width of screen programmatically and devide it by the number of images to set the result as the image width (hard-coding).

Comment: Use  android:adjustViewBounds="true" in ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

replace your code of `imageview` with

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_audio"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following Layout do the trick (I modified the code from your question. Modify according your needs)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back_main"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/foo" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/bar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/foobar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Depending the images you're using, consider using a "android:scaleType" in the ImageViews.